# http post request crashing

Tags: c#, java, http, request

I'm trying to excecute some post request, I censored the site because it has some sensitive data.. Well here's the code:

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.someaddress.com"); 
        // Add your data   
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);   
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sdata", ""));

        try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8));
                Log.d("MyTag", "works till here.");
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                   // String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
             //       Log.d("MyTag", responseBody);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

It crashes on that line:

```
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Here's the logcat which really says nothing to me:
http://pastebin.com/F0YAiNLD

What could be the problem? Why is it crashing?
I'm trying to translate this C# code to JAVA. The C# code works but the JAVA code isn't.

Here's the C# code:

```
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    string pData = "";
    byte[] sdata = encoding.GetBytes(pData);
    HttpWebRequest request = new HttpWebRequest(new Uri("http://www.someaddress.com"));
    request.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = sdata.Length;
    Stream nStream=request.GetRequestStream();
    nStream.Write(sdata,0,sdata.Length);
    nStream.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response = 
    (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Android developer but a simple Google search for "Android NetworkOnMainThreadException" shows that [this exception is thrown when you attempt to do network actions on the main event thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) (the name is pretty self-descriptive), and that [instead you should be making these type of network calls on a background thread](http://www.techblogistech.com/2011/11/how-to-fix-the-android-networkonmainthreadexception/).

Typically in GUI apps it is a bad idea to do work in the main thread that can block (such as a network HTTP call) since it will block the main animation loop.